# How do I enable Javascript syntax check in Apple Instruments

Tags: javascript, ios, parsing, instruments, ios-ui-automation

We are using Apple Instruments to automate some of the Test Flows on iPhone devices. For a a MAC OS X Lion machine, Instruments does not show any JavaScript syntax errors, however it does on MAC OS X Leopard.

Any clues on why this might be affecting Lion machine?

Lion - iOS SDK 5.1 : No JavaScript syntax error

Leopard - iOS SDK 5.0 : JavaScript syntax errors are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an undocumented BUG in Instruments with XCode 4.4.1.

I can see that Instruments now displays stack trace and Javascript parse errors after upgrading to Xcode 4.5 (iOS SDK 6.0)